# ORACLE12 - Connect Via SqlPlus

Tags: oracle-12c, sqlplus, debian

I have a local installation of Oracle
Before i can connect directly via SqlPlus
but now when i try to connect i have this error :

> ERROR:
>   ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
>   ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
>   Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
>   Additional information: 3640
>   Additional information: 684464879
>   Process ID: 0
>   Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

Can you tell me what is the cause of this Error ?
how can i solve it ?

Comment: How did you start your database that you try to access? Normally you get this error if the database is not open.

Comment: I tried to start the database and they said it s already started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing the value of

> "kernel.shmall" in the file /etc/sysctl.conf

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the database is actually running, and if not, start it. If you have an init script, then it's typically something like:

```
sudo service oracle start
```

This has been asked before for Oracle 11g - the answers and comments to that question may be helpful here:
[ORA-01034: ORACLE not available in oracle 11g](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/78861/ora-01034-oracle-not-available-in-oracle-11g)

Comment: The database is actually running
and it s not ORACLE XE
i already saw this questions but didn't work for me